# How do I correctly perform form validation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am having a hard time trying to do a correct form validation. I have Name, Email, and Phone Number fields. I implemented the validation check for all of them and when I click on the submit query, it returns email as false, but not anything else. It also will still submit the form. How do I fix this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GVQpL/

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function validateForm(/*fullName, email, phoneNumber*/)
{
    //-------------------------NAME VALIDATION-----------------------------//
    var fullNameV = document.forms["queryForm"]["fullName"].value;
    if (fullNameV == null || fullNameV == "")
    {
        alert("Name must be filled out!");
        return false;
    }
    else if(fullNameV.indexOf(" ") <= fullNameV.length)
    {
        alert("Not a valid name");
        return false;
    }

    //-------------------------EMAIL VALIDATION-----------------------------//
    var emailV = document.forms["queryForm"]["email"].value;
    if (emailV == null || emailV == "")
    {
         alert("Email must be filled out!");
         return false;
    }
    var atpos = emailV.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = emailV.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length)
    {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }

    //-------------------------PHONE # VALIDATION-----------------------------//
    var phoneNumberV = document.forms["queryForm"]["phoneNumber"].value;
    if (phoneNumberV == null || phoneNumberV == "")
    {
        alert("Phone Number must be filled out!");
        return false;
    }
    var error = "";
    var stripped = phoneNumberV.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');    

    if (phoneNumberV == "") 
    {
        error = alert("You didn't enter a phone number.\n");
        phoneNumberV.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } 
    else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) 
    {
        error = alert("The phone number contains illegal characters.\n");
        phoneNumberV.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } 
    else if (!(stripped.length == 10)) 
    {
        error = alert("The phone number is the wrong length. Make sure you included an area code.\n");
        phoneNumberV.style.background = 'Yellow';
    }
    return error;
}
```

Comment: for one `alert` does not return a value so there is no point in saving it to `error`

Comment: @PatrickEvans - agreed, but that's the inefficiency you pull from this? there is a lot of room for improvement here.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea, no it was just the first thing i saw, plus this is the comment section not exactly the place to list all improvements that could be made.

Comment: @PatrickEvans - touche, sir. touche.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your fiddle's html for the function to be called `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` and removed the `required="required"` changed your function to work, you can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/GVQpL/3/

```
        function validateForm(/*fullName, email, phoneNumber*/)
        {
            //-------------------------NAME VALIDATION-----------------------------//
            var fullNameV = document.forms["queryForm"]["fullName"].value;
            if (fullNameV == null || fullNameV == "")
            {
                alert("Name must be filled out!");
                document.forms["queryForm"]["fullName"].focus();
                return false;
            }
            else if(fullNameV.indexOf(" ") >= fullNameV.length)
            {
                alert("Not a valid name");
                document.forms["queryForm"]["fullName"].focus();
                return false;
            }

            //-------------------------EMAIL VALIDATION-----------------------------//
            var emailV = document.forms["queryForm"]["email"].value;
            if (emailV == null || emailV == "")
            {
                alert("Email must be filled out!");
                document.forms["queryForm"]["email"].focus();
                return false;
            }

            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
if(!emailReg.test(emailV)){

                alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                document.forms["queryForm"]["email"].focus();
                return false;
            }

            //-------------------------PHONE # VALIDATION-----------------------------//
            var phoneNumberV = document.forms["queryForm"]["phoneNumber"].value;
            if (phoneNumberV == null || phoneNumberV == "")
            {
                alert("Phone Number must be filled out!");
                document.forms["queryForm"]["phoneNumber"].focus();
                return false;
            }
            var error = "";
            var stripped = phoneNumberV.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');    

            if (phoneNumberV == "") 
            {
                alert("You didn't enter a phone number.\n");
                document.forms["queryForm"]["phoneNumber"].focus()
                document.forms["queryForm"]["phoneNumber"].style.background = 'Yellow';
                return false;
            } 
            else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) 
            {
             alert("The phone number contains illegal characters.\n");
                document.forms["queryForm"]["phoneNumber"].focus();
                document.forms["queryForm"]["phoneNumber"].style.background = 'Yellow';
                return false;
            } 
            else if (!(stripped.length == 10)) 
            {
                alert("The phone number is the wrong length. Make sure you included an area code.\n");
                document.forms["queryForm"]["phoneNumber"].focus();
                document.forms["queryForm"]["phoneNumber"].style.background = 'Yellow';
                return false;
            }
            if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to submit your DSLR query?')){
                return false;   
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! I am closer now, but still have a problem at the end where the submit button doesn't do anything or is assumed to return false. The form validation returns true, but the `queryForm.onsubmit function()` does not bring up the message to successfully submit query. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GVQpL/2/

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight update the code, there was an issue with the function was returning false in all cases by mistake. And you don't need to make stuff complicated, just add the confirm prompt at the end of the function after all tests are passed, check the new fiddle

Comment: Okay, I updated my code and did as you said, but it still isn't doing anything when I click the submit button. http://jsfiddle.net/GVQpL/4/

Comment: man first you don't need this: `queryForm.onsubmit = function(){` as you're already inside a function that is called on submit. and you don't need this: `if(!nameValid || !emailValid || !phoneNumberValid){ return valid = false;}` as you're return false at each test that doesn't pass. and you don't need to `return x=false;` just `return false;` check out: http://jsfiddle.net/GVQpL/5/ updated your final code

Comment: Oh I see the problem now! Thanks a lot for fixing it!